# VSCode kill running processes

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, lldb

I have been using 
Python debug and LLDB attach debug since I have code in Python and C++

I have run this multiple times. It looks like everytime there is an exception in the middle of debugging, the process doesn't get killed.

As a result, now after multiple runs, when I try to use LLDB Attach debug it shows multiple instances of the same file being run

Unable to know which is the latest process

Also how to kill processes that haven't terminated.

For reference, here's an image
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those processes can probably be termed as `ghost processes`. Those are caused from the previous run when one does not detach the lldb from it.

Manually searching for the process ID of those and killing them solved the problem.

List python related processes

```
ps -ef | grep python
```

Killing the ones you identify as ghost.

```
kill -9 <process-id>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I was unable to do that coz Stack Exchange needs you to accept your own answer, only after certain hours have passed (i guess 24 hours)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to command line, you should be able to see that ghost python process in the process explorer (command "Open Process Explorer"), and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to kill it.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> is available in VSCode 1.75 (Jan. 2023), or right now in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), with [issue 119345](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119345) and [PR 168943](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/168943) delivered.