# kill doesn't actually terminate the ghost process

Tags: terminal, process, ghost-blog

In order to terminate the ghost process (process which hasn't terminated properly and hence it still pending to be killed)
I used the

```
kill -9 <process-id>
```

At times it works perfectly, and when I check the process after killing it, it is gone

```
ps -aux | grep python
```

However, surprisingly, now I am able to see the ghost process even after the `kill` command. What's the problem?

[image: Ghost process 23756]

In the image above, I tried to kill the process with id 23756 but it still appears in `ps aux`

Referring to my answer to previous question of Visual Studio ghost process

[VSCode kill running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319671/vscode-kill-running-processes/52337664#52337664)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, I had to close the debug process that was still incomplete. Basically, killing the application or closing the debug or something on those lines, helps you to terminate the ghost process.

Comment: However, in another scenario, when I tried to close the debug process still it persisted. It's likely caused by this error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749108/visual-studio-debug-error-unrecognized-format-of-field-msg-in-result